# Can I change between OSes?

Tags: dual-boot

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I'm new.  I'm running on OS X so, if I download and install Ubuntu and I start using Ubuntu, but for some reason I want to use OSX for a while to see something, can I change to OSX and then go back to Ubuntu??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Replacing one operating system with another

**YES**, there is no reason why you can't install over your Ubuntu with OS X and visa versa as many times as you like.

### Using more than one operating system on the same computer

Installing 2 operating systems on the same computer is called "dual-booting" (or "multi-booting"). It depends on how you do the installation (it's a slightly different process with OSX and Ubuntu than it is with Windows and Ubuntu), but here again, the answer is **YES**.